# How to mount Mac OS X Lion fileshare?

Tags: samba, macosx

How can I mount OS X 10.7 Lion shares on my Ubuntu box (10.10, 11.4)?

Since OS X 10.7 Lion update, network integration with Ubuntu is a nightmare. Previously we could print on OSX printers and mount OSX file shares in a snap, using SMB/CIFS.

Now I got to print on OSX Lion printers using CUPS and IPP sharing... DONE! no samba: it works.

Worst I cannot anymore access files on OS X Lion shares (it was OK up to Snow Leopard).

Exactly from Nautilus I can still browse the OSX server shares, mount one of them (using Nautilus and `smb://` URL), I can even browse all the share's directory tree, but whenever I try to open a file (even for read-only)

I receive the error

```
Impossible to open file <<smb://<host>/<share>/<file-path>> Unexpected error: Function not implemented
```

(this is Konqueror);

When trying to mount.cifs, it reports to me

```
root@UL30AL64:/home/fmoli# mount.cifs //<host>/<myshare> /media/gw-fm -o user=<myname>,password=<mypwd>,nounix,noserverino,sec=krb5
mount error(126): Required key not available
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Rumours in the net tell that SAMBA4 is the recipe for Linux/Ubuntu.
But I tried to set-up samba4 without any luck (very lack of guides around...)

Other ones suggest to install netatalk on Ubuntu. But netatalk is a "server-only" package: I need to mount OSX shares on Ubuntu, not Ubuntu shares on OSX !

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Ubuntu 11.10, can't mount OS X Lion SMB/CIFS shares like before.

Answer (score 10):

With reference to [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3196311?start=30&tstart=0) in Apple discussion community, you can try to mount with additional two options: `nounix,sec=ntlmssp`

I've tried that, it works properly:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.0.x/public /mnt/public -o user=myusername,password=mypassword,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,noperm,rw
```

Comment: Hi Sengtui,thank you very much for your answer, I tested it and it works, undoubtedly. Still it's as a bit unconfortable, as I have to mount / unmount via CLI, and I cannot do this via Nautilus GUI, nor even use credentials sdtored in keyring.... but it works!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, though I'm disappointed it means I have to drop to the command line every time I want to mount an SMB/CIFS share on OS X. With the features they've removed and now this, I'm tempted to go back to Snow Leopard.

Comment: You just saved my mac from being influenced with a sledgehammer.  Many thanks.

Comment: What would be a `/etc/fstab` version of this command?

Comment: "invalid argument".  granted, it's no longer Lion.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is more generalized and will let you access files on OS X from Ubuntu 11.10, though now via SMB/CIFS. On OS X Lion, enable Remote Login in Sharing, add your user so that you can access it, and then on Ubuntu 11.10 it should show up in Browse Network accessible as SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/etc/fstab` as well:

```
//192.168.0.x/public    /mnt/public    cifs    credentials=/root/.credentialsfile,iocharset=utf8,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,noperm,rw
```

the `/root/.credentialsfile` would look like:

```
username=myusername
password=mypassword
```